# JSF : How to create a modal link with onclick action?

Tags: javascript, jsf, onclick

I don't know JSF and i have to modify a JSF web page. I must add the following :

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" id="#mymodal" onclick="openModal()">
                                                     Link   
                                                    </a>
```

But in JSF i don't know how to write it. Could you help me please ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "modal link". And this exact piece of code works in a JSF page too. You can use plain html in a facelets page

Answer (score 1):

The cool thing about a JSF page, is that **it supports plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript as well**.

You can place any of them in your page and will be sent to the browser, but they will not be considered as JSF components.

If your project uses Primefaces, you can open a modal dialog on a button or or link easily with `p:dialog` component. See : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml. This way the dialog is part of the JSF component tree.

If not, you can still embed JQuery UI by yourself with referring to a CDN or import it with `h:outputScript` and use the JQuery Dialog component.

Primefaces uses Jquery UI indeed.

Comment: is it possible to add a plain html into jsf page ?

Comment: As @Kukeltje said, and I : YES !

Comment: How to add the following plain html into my JSF file "<a href="" data-toggle="modal" id="#mymodal" onclick="openModal()">
                                                     Link   
                                                    </a>" ?

Comment: CTLR+C , CTRL+V ;-) Put it every where on your page in the body section in order to appear where you want in the browser. Post your whole JSF Page to help you more precisely.